# How to get duration from an employee clock in clock out system

Tags: sql, sql-server

I m currently struggling to get the time duration for each employee from a clock in clock out system.
  Basically I have a transaction table which saves all the clock in clock out info.
For example, the table records look like this:

```
    Name        |       Time           |  Action 
 employee A     |   20170327 08:30:00  |   in 
 employee B     |   20170327 08:35:00  |   in
 employee A     |   20170327 12:30:00  |   out 
 employee A     |   20170327 13:20:00  |   in 
 employee B     |   20170327 17:30:00  |   out 
 employee A     |   20170327 17:20:00  |   out 
 employee C     |   20170327 09:00:00  |   in
```

For each clock in tap or clock out tap, there will be an record inserted into this table, I want to get the duration between each of the nearest 2 records for the same person, so the query result i want to get would be something like this:

```
   Name   |    Duration From    |   Duration To
    A     |  20170327 08:30:00  | 20170327 12:30:00
    A     |  20170327 13:20:00  | 20170327 17:20:00
    B     |  20170327 08:35:00  | 20170327 17:30:00
    C     |  20170327 09:00:00  |   NULL
```

Here is the query which i had so far:

```
    Select name,min(StartTime) as DurationFrom,max(EndTime) as DurationTo
from 
    (select name, case Action when 'in' then time end as startTime,
                 case Action when 'out' then time end as endTime 
from dbo.transaction)main
    group by name
```

And this is the result i got so far:

```
   Name   |    Duration From    |   Duration To
    A     |  20170327 08:30:00  | 20170327 17:20:00
    B     |  20170327 08:35:00  | 20170327 17:30:00
    C     |  20170327 09:00:00  |   NULL
```

Can someone pls help me on this issue? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join all in taps to out taps.

```
select s.name,  s.[time]  as startTime, min(e.[time]) as endTime 
from dbo.[transaction] s
left join dbo.[transaction] e
on s.name = e.name 
and e.Action='out'
and s.[time]< e.[time]
where s.Action='in'
group by s.name, s.[time]
```

Comment: Your `where` clause changes the `left join` to an `inner join`. All conditions on the right table should be placed in the `on` clause.

Comment: Also, keywords must be enclosed in `[]` - `[transaction], [end]`.